# Why does the popup get corrupted after returning to a tab?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a scenario: fillout form on https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator and click email estimate (a pop-up window opens),  then open and switch to new tab (https://yopmail.com/en/email-generator) and copy random email, then switch to previous tab (https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) . And after that popup (Email Your Estimate) becomes weird, inactive, but in manual testing everything is ok. What's the problem?

[GIF record with a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ac1s.gif)

```
public void fillOutForm() {
    estimatePage = new GoogleCloudHomePage(driver)
    .openPage()
    .search(SEARCH_TERM)
    .goToPricingCalculatorFromSearchResults()
    .switchToCalculatorFrame()
    .selectComputeEngineItem()
    .setNumberOfInstances(NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES)
    .setOperatingSystem(OPERATING_SYSTEM)
    .setMachineClass(MACHINE_CLASS)
    .setSeries(SERIES)
    .setMachineType(MACHINE_TYPE)
    .setGPU(NUMBER_OF_GPUS, GPU_TYPE)
    .setLocalSSD(LOCAL_SSD)
    .setDatacenterLocation(DATACENTER_LOCATION)
    .setCommittedUsage(COMMITTED_USAGE)
    .addToEstimate();
    emailEstimatePage = estimatePage.goToEmailEstimate();
    tabManager = new TabManager(driver);
    tabManager.openNewTab();
    tabManager.switchToTab(1);
    emailGeneratorPage = new YopmailHomePage(driver)
        .openPage()
        .generateNewEmailAddress()
        .copyEmailAddress();
    tabManager.switchToTab(0);
```

//THE PROBLEM IS HERE. POP-UP CORRUPTED CAN'T FIND ELEMENT ON THIS STEP/ watch gif

```
  emailEstimatePage.switchToContentFrame();
    emailEstimatePage.setEmail(); 
    emailEstimatePage.sendEmail();
    tabManager.switchToTab(1);
    emailInboxPage = new YopmailHomePage(driver)
        .openPage()
        .goToEmailInboxPage()
        .getGoogleCloudEstimateMessage();
  }
```

code of TabManager

```
public class TabManager {

  public WebDriver driver;

  public TabManager(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

  public void openNewTab() {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
  }

  public void switchToTab(int tabIndex) {
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabIndex));
  }
}
```

Comment: Both methods contains `tabManager.switchToTab(1);`. Shouldn't one of them be with index 0? Btw you can get random email address before your test begins or generate it different way.

Comment: at the beginning i open new tab and switch to it. then tabManager.switchToTab(0);

Comment: At mailinator.com you don't need to specifiy address to recieve emails, simply generate/think up an address send an email and check mailbox.

Comment: @pburgr
problem is not in email generating. i don't understand why the popup gets weird after returning, but when manually testing it is ok